# CTE (`with` keyword) in the beginning of query rejected by ms odbc driver for sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dplyr, odbc, rstudio

I have a query that looks like this:

```
WITH test_query AS (
SELECT DISTINCT 
   DOB
   , Age
   ,CONVERT(date,md.DateDTS) [MDDate]
   ,CONVERT(date,ep.LastAppointmentDTS) [Last Appointment Date]
   ,CONVERT(date,ep.NextAppointmentDTS) [Next Appointment Date]
 FROM
   EveryPerson ep
 INNER JOIN
   Meds MD ON ep.PersonID = MD.PersonID )

 SELECT DOB
   , Age
   ,MIN([MDDate]) [Earliest Date]
   ,MAX([MDDate]) [Latest Date]
   ,MAX([Last Appointment Date]) [LastAppointment]
   ,MIN([Next Appointment Date]) [NextAppointment]
   FROM test_query
   GROUP BY DOB, Age;
```

The ODBC driver 17 for SQL server rejects the query saying "*Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon*". The problem is that there is no previous statement in my SQL file. I have been searching for an answer and many people suggest putting a semicolon before the With keyword which I tried but that gives an error too. (incorrect syntax near `;`)The query runs fine on the SQL Server and it only fails when it is passed to the ODBC driver (by Rstudio).

Comment: This could be a problem with RStudio. Ref: [Why does dplyr::tbl wrap a CTE in a subquery for SQL Server dbb's but not for RSQLite?](https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-does-dplyr-tbl-wrap-a-cte-in-a-subquery-for-sql-server-dbbs-but-not-for-rsqlite/65783)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thank you. I think you may be right. That forum post you linked seems relevant but does not let you see the answer received by the poster for some reason.

Comment: My rule is always start with `;With cte` as here [Why should a CTE start with a semi-colon?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23371/why-should-a-cte-start-with-a-semi-colon)

Comment: @AnelHodžić When I start with `;With` I get an incorrect syntax error due to `;` as mentioned in the question for the same reason that @AlwaysLearning mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: If you can't find a way to stop it doing that then the stuff in a CTE can easily be moved into a derived table here. `SELECT DOB , Age ,MIN([MDDate]) [Earliest Date] ...    FROM (SELECT ...) AS test_query GROUP BY DOB, Age`

Comment: @MartinSmith Thank you. That helped. If this was an answer, I would accept it. :)